# VPN-connection still encrypted after passing through the VPN-server?

Tags: vpn

I want to build the connection through a VPN-server. Is this connection still encrypted when it leaves the server? Or is it only as long encrypted until it reaches the VPN-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) :
"A VPN is created by establishing a virtual *point-to-point* connection".
"Point-to-point" is not "point-to-point-to-point".

After the VPN server, the next connection step needs to be at least HTTPS to
be encrypted.